# How to position my button to the Bottom of the Screen? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Below is my code to make a View in SwiftUI. I want to position my **Welcome button** to the bottom of the screen as shown below.

```
struct welcomeViewControllerView: View {
      var body: some View {
            Text("Welcome")
              .font(.system(size: 20, design: .rounded))
              .padding(.leading)
              .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
              .background(

            Image("splashBackground")
              .resizable()
              .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
              .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        
            Button(action:{print("button pressed")})
              {
                Text("Continue")
                .font(.system(size: 20, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
               .background((Image("buttonImage")).resizable().frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center))      
         }
      }
   }

class welcomeViewController: UIHostingController<welcomeViewControllerView> {
        required init?(coder: NSCoder)
         {
             super.init(coder: coder,rootView: welcomeViewControllerView());
          }
    
          override func viewDidLoad()
         {
           super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = .white
         }
}
```

How can I position my button to the bottom of the screen? I posted the screen below. I am fairly new to using SwiftUI.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Group{
                Text("Welcome!")
                    .font(.title)
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("tapped!")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Continue")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .padding()
                })
            }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What is **position** for then. Dayum SwiftUI

Answer (score 8):

Your question included a background image, the code below uses ZStack and Spacer to get the layout with a background underneath. Spacer is definitely your friend to push content horizontally or vertically.

For the background, because it is mostly black, I used Color.black to paint the entire screen and assume you could use a smaller image for the logo. This lets you ship a way smaller image which won't distort. Separating the screen color also lets you match the device light/dark mode settings. See Color(UIColor.systemBackground) and @Environment(.colorScheme) if interested.

```
ZStack {
    Color.black
    
    Text("Welcome")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.title)
    
    VStack {
        Image(systemName:"flame.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .frame(height:100)
            .padding([.top], 20)
        Spacer() // will spread content to top and bottom of VStack
        Button(action:{print("Continue")}){
            Text("Continue")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        Spacer()
            .frame(height:50)  // limit spacer size by applying a frame
    }
}
```

Above gets you below:
[Layout with bkg using ZStack and Spacer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skIag.png)

Answer (score 2):

use safeAreaInset.

```
    VStack() {

    }.safeAreaInset(edge: VerticalEdge.bottom) {
Text("Sticky Button")
}
```

Comment: This is only good for iOS 15+ implementations