# How to align a button at the bottom of the screen

Tags: swiftui

I want to align the button at the bottom of the screen while the bigger view stays in the middle of the screen. I tried to do it with .frame() modifier and spacer but I couldn't. Here is my code and the preview.

[image]

```
ZStack {
    BackgroundView()
    
    VStack {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Choose", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            DatePicker("Bedtime", selection: $bedtime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            DatePicker("Waking up time", selection: $wakingUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            
            InfoText(timeInterval: timeInterval)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 15)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.gray.opacity(0.1))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2)
                .foregroundStyle(.gray.opacity(0.5))
        )
        .padding()
        
        Button {} label: {
            Text("Sleep guidelines by age")
                .bold()
                .foregroundStyle(.purple)
                .padding()
                .background(.purple.opacity(0.1))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .foregroundStyle(.purple.opacity(0.6))
                )
                .shadow(color: .white.opacity(0.3), radius: 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135725/how-to-position-my-button-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen-swiftui

Answer (score 3):

You just need to apply `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` to the inner `VStack`. This way, it will occupy as much of the screen height as possible, which will cause the button to be pushed to the bottom.

Like this:

```swift
ZStack {
    BackgroundView()

    VStack {
        VStack {
            // content as before
        }
        // other modifiers as before
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity) // <- ADDED

        Button {

        } label: {
            // content as before
        }
    }
}
```